# Strange forEach behaviour in nodejs

Tags: node.js, foreach, node-redis

I am creating a nodejs and redis API service, I have written the code below to find out individual dates from a date range and then get timeslot of each date and store it in redis.

The issue is I am doing a `console.log("Keys :"+key)` inside a forEach and checking for keys inside the same forEach but for some reason loop is executing individual functions separately.

I am attaching the code and console output to better explain the issue

```
//API to get slot for a particular date range
app.get('/listcapacity/:ticketid/:fromdate/:todate', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.ticketid;
    var fromdate = req.params.fromdate;
    var todate = req.params.todate;
    var key = null;
    var username = 'foo';
    var password = 'foobar';
    var result = {};
    var data_output = [];
    var currentDate = new Date(fromdate);
    var between = [];
    var end = new Date(todate);

    while (currentDate <= end) {
        var tempdate = new Date(currentDate).toISOString();
        var dump = tempdate.toString().split("T");
        between.push(dump[0]);
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    between.forEach(function(entry) {
        key = id+entry+"list";
        console.log("Keys: " + key);
        client.exists(key, function(err, reply) {
            if (reply === 1) {
                console.log("Key : " + key + " Found");
                client.get(key, function(err, reply) {
                    var output = JSON.parse(reply);
                    data_output = data_output.concat(output);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Key : " + key + " Not Found");

                process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
                var slot_url = "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@testapi.foobar.com/1/timeslots?productId=" + id + "&fromDate=" + entry + "&toDate=" + entry;
                request({

                    url: slot_url,
                    json: true,
                    headers: headers
                }, function(error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        var data = [];
                        try {
                            var temp = {};
                            body.data.forEach(function(tempslots) {
                                temp['date'] = tempslots['date'];
                                temp['timeslots'] = tempslots['timeslots'];
                                data = data.concat(temp);
                            });
                            client.set(key, JSON.stringify(data));
                            data_output = data_output.concat(data);
                        } catch (err) {

                            console.log(err.message);

                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong!! " + error.message);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    });
    result['data'] = data_output;
    result['response'] = 1;
    result['message'] = 'Capacity list fetched successfully!';
    res.json(result);

});
```

And here is the console output

```
Keys: 5212016-10-01list
Keys: 5212016-10-02list
Keys: 5212016-10-03list
Keys: 5212016-10-04list
Keys: 5212016-10-05list
Key : 5212016-10-05list Not Found
Key : 5212016-10-05list Not Found
Key : 5212016-10-05list Not Found
Key : 5212016-10-05list Not Found
Key : 5212016-10-05list Found
```

As you can see the keys value when checking with redis is only getting the last value where as inside the very same loop when i define the keys it has the correct value as is being printed in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the redis operation is async. So the callback will get executed in the next tick. So by that time the key variable is the last variable.

You should use local variables.